# Paypal recurring payments failed after merging the contact. How to fix?

Tags: payment-processor, recurring-contributions, paypal

2 contacts were crated for the same person due to some typo of the donor while given donation online. one of the contact record had a recurring payment setup. I have merged them both using the menu. But i think i have merged the wrong way around. now paypal is not able to process the payment because there is no contact record by ID 1212 (it was deleted permanently, not available in trash).

Newer contact record ID is 1313. is there a way to change the ID of this new one to 1212 so the payment gets processed?

This is from civi log

```
Jul 04 14:04:05  [info] $POST = Array
(
    [payment_cycle] => Monthly
    [txn_type] => recurring_payment_skipped
    [last_name] => Entc
    [next_payment_date] => 03:00:00 Jul 09, 2015 PDT
    [residence_country] => GB
    [initial_payment_amount] => 0.00
    [rp_invoice_id] => i=e45c4d0dad9c6a9a0693799f8c99d38f&m=contribute&c=1212&r=4&b=17212&p=6
    [currency_code] => GBP
....)

    Jul 04 14:04:05  [info] Could not find contact record: 1212 in IPN request: Array
    (
        [component] => contribute
        [invoice] => e45c4d0dad9c6a9a0693799f8c99d38f
        [txnType] => recurring_payment_skipped
        [paymentStatus] => 
        [amount] => 
        [reasonCode] => 
        [first_name] => Eli
        [last_name] => Entc
......   )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you create a new contact with just a first and last name (no address, phone, or anything else that might go in a separate table somewhere) and then change that new contact's ID in the database to 1212? Then you could merge again, making sure to keep the new contact and transfer all of the other information over during the merge. (Try on a copy of the database of course)

Answer (score 3):

Glad you found an answer.  An alternative solution would be to log into PayPal - you can change the parameters of a recurring payment IPN manually in Paypal.  Note that last I checked, they use some Javascript to limit the length of the field where you can change the URL, and they limit it to less than the full permitted length.  When I change the URL manually, I often have to use Firebug/developer tools to edit the value rather than manually type into the field.